# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier - set Identifier & class in storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableView with its class set to TableViewController. In storyboard, I click on the cell and set it to the class MyCell. Also in storyboard, I set the identifier to "MyCell". I then copy & paste that into

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
```

What step did I miss? I triple checked that the Identifier string is exactly the same. The tableView and cell are set to the correct classes.

Comment: please check the Attribute inspector tab again and make sure MyCell is indeed in Identifier field. I had this issue a few times already.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was deleting the `, for: indexPath` part.